# javascript inheritance. Please explain profile results

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, profiling

In my classes I use next code to call parent method:

```
mdi.Class.TControl.superClass.method.apply( context, arguments );
```

But I am lazy and was boring to type so much. So I did closure:

```
{
  var inherit = function( context, method, params ) {
    mdi.Class.TControl.superClass[ method ].apply( context, arguments );
    };
....

  someMethod: function() {
    inherit( this, 'someMethod', arguments )  
  }
}
```

Now I am glad to not type much and want to profile how times trick with closure slower versus direct call.

**Must it be slower because of extra call wrapper function, must not?**

so, I create in parent class empty function

```
test: function() {
}
```

and code to profile looks as:

```
console.time( 'it' );
for( var i=0; i< 10000000; i++ ) {
 inherit( this, 'test', [ 1, 2 ,3, 4 ] );
}
console.timeEnd( 'it' );  

console.time( 'it2' );
for( var i=0; i< 10000000; i++ ) {
 mdi.Class.TControl.superClass[ 'test' ].apply( this, [ 1,2 ,3 ,4 ] );
}
console.timeEnd( 'it2' );
```

Results surprise me.

```
it: start timer TControl.js:712
it: 244.99ms TControl.js:716
it2: start timer TControl.js:718
it2: 2004.52ms TControl.js:722
it: start timer TControl.js:712
it: 241.27ms TControl.js:716
it2: start timer TControl.js:718
it2: 2011.2ms TControl.js:722
it: start timer TControl.js:712
it: 240.78ms TControl.js:716
it2: start timer TControl.js:718
it2: 1986.68ms TControl.js:722
it: start timer TControl.js:712
it: 246.62ms TControl.js:716
it2: start timer TControl.js:718
it2: 2020.63ms
```

Case with closure **TEN TIME FASTER!!!**. Why?? How is it be possible?